# How to get SHOW CREATE TABLE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get CREATE TABLE script for an existing Table, similar to MySQL SHOW CREATE TABLE. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigQuery now supports a DDL column in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#tables_view), which gives you the CREATE TABLE (or VIEW) DDL statement.

Note that the DDL column is hidden if you do `SELECT * FROM I_S.TABLE`, you need to query the view like:

```sql
SELECT
   table_name, ddl
 FROM
   `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE
   table_name="population_by_zip_2010"
```

gives you

```
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       table_name       |                                                                                                            ddl                                                                                                             |
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| population_by_zip_2010 | CREATE TABLE `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_usa.population_by_zip_2010`                                                                                                                                               |
|                        | (                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|                        |   geo_id STRING OPTIONS(description="Geo code"),                                                                                                                                                                           |
|                        |   zipcode STRING NOT NULL OPTIONS(description="Five digit ZIP Code Tabulation Area Census Code"),                                                                                                                          |
|                        |   population INT64 OPTIONS(description="The total count of the population for this segment."),                                                                                                                             |
|                        |   minimum_age INT64 OPTIONS(description="The minimum age in the age range. If null, this indicates the row as a total for male, female, or overall population."),                                                          |
|                        |   maximum_age INT64 OPTIONS(description="The maximum age in the age range. If null, this indicates the row as having no maximum (such as 85 and over) or the row is a total of the male, female, or overall population."), |
|                        |   gender STRING OPTIONS(description="male or female. If empty, the row is a total population summary.")                                                                                                                    |
|                        | )                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|                        | OPTIONS(                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|                        |   labels=[("freebqcovid", "")]                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|                        | );                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```